# How can I extract the tags and content of children using xml-conduit?

Tags: haskell, xml-conduit

**UPDATE: After many different attempts I have for now concluded that the behaviour seen below is expected and that I am only running into difficulties because I am using ToJson later on. Will update if I solve it completely.**

**==============================================================**

I am trying to use xml-conduit to achieve this:

- go down the cursor of a document to the  element of an html document.
- treat any descendants of this node as text. i.e. don't only get the content as text, but also the tags themselves.

so for example, **I edited this example as per my comments below**

> ```
> <ol> 
>    <li class="c1"> 
>       this is really "good work" <i>John</i>.
>    </li>
> </ol>
> ```

should return

> ```
> "<li class="c1"> this is really "good work" <i>John</i> </li>"
> ```

Whereas I'm getting

> " "\u003cli class=\"c1\"\u003e this is really "good work"\u003ci\u003eJohn\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/li\u003e

So there is something going on within the tags that is different from what is happening to the content. I think perhaps the ToHtml instance isnt quite what i want really. I just want to *collapse* all descendants, turn their tags and content into text. I can't find a way though.

```
import Text.Blaze.Html                           (toHtml, preEscapedToHtml)
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Utf8             (renderHtml)
--import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String           (renderHtml)
--import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text             (renderHtml)
import           Data.Text.Encoding              (decodeUtf8)
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy            (toStrict)


extractAllParas :: Cursor -> [ Text ]
extractAllParas c = do
  let mt' = c $/ laxElement "body"  &// laxElement "ol" &/ anyElement
      mt =  (map (decodeUtf8 . toStrict . renderHtml . toHtml . node) $ mt')
  case mt of
    [ "" ] -> []
    paras -> formatParas paras
```

formatParas :: [ Text ] -> [ Text ]

Comment: Can you supply an example of your HTML input?

Comment: I am loading a Utf8 encoded local file. i would like all the ancestors of the elements in the <ol> element to be "collapsed" and stored as Text with their tags, and the special characters therein, retained and stored as Text. In fact I noticed, I made a mistake above. following example html:

`<ol>
   <li> Hi there <i> user05402 </i> </li>
</ol>`

should be 
` "<li> Hi there <i> user05402 </i> </li>" :: Text `

Comment: (ran out of editing time, sorry)

Where as I am getting "\u003cli\u003e Hi there \u003ci\u003euser05402\u003e\u003c/i\u003e \u003e\u003c/li\u003e"

Also, special chars within the content, e.g. ", are then turned into &quot;